# GDI+ With C++Builder?

Tags: c++, gdi+, c++builder

How do I use **GDI+** with **C++Builder**? Can someone give me a simple example of creating a surface and drawing a circle on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be similar to coding a normal Windows program in C using Visual Studio.

Basically:

- include "gdiplus.h"
- link to gdiplus.lib
- call GdiPlusStartup at the start of your program (before main window creation)
- call GdiPlusShutdown at the end of your program (after the message loop has ended and the main window's been destroyed)

Here's a link with a sample program:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533895(v=VS.85).aspx

MSDN contains much information on this topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533802(v=VS.85).aspx